# Get current month with Calendar.getDisplayName()

Tags: java, android, calendar

I'm trying to get the current month using the following code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String mes = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The problem is that it is returning `March` instead of `April`, can anyone help me understanding why is this happening?

The system's date is correct, it has as month `April`.

Comment: The system date of what? Are you testing this on a device or on an emulator?

Comment: @popovitsj I'm programming this in Android and testing in my phone but i used the Log.d to check what is being returned.

Comment: What does it show when you format it like this: `DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT);
String formattedDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());`

Comment: can you try to get your timezone and check whether it's same with your system date or not?

Comment: @popovitsj, the result is: 30/03/15 00:00

Comment: @kucing_terbang it's the same

Comment: I had in my code calendar.clear(), I commented it and it works.